# Is there any official documentation on the AdSense data-adtest="on" parameter to test locally?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

On many places over the internet you can find people suggesting the `data-adtest="on"` parameter to test ads on your local environment.

```
<ins className="adsbygoogle"
  style={{display:"inline-block", width:"360px", height:"180px"}}
  data-ad-client="XXXXX"
  data-ad-slot="XXXXX"
  data-adtest="on"         // <-----------------------------
>
</ins>
```

I could make it work with trial and error. Some sites even suggest that the proper name is `data-ad-test`.

But is there an official documentation about this?

If there is, I still haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like **there isn't**.

> I also tried the data-adtest="on" approach and it didnt work for me either.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043177/how-do-you-render-google-ad-units-in-localhost

I couldn't find any official documentation about this parameter either.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Testing modes](https://developers.google.com/ad-placement/docs/test)

I found in the google developers site. Hope this will help.